# sqlplus :: ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle19c

I have a brand new Oracle 19c Docker image fresh installed today.

If I run `sqlplus / as sysdba` I can successfully login but when I run `SELECT * FROM all_users;` SQL says:

```
SELECT * FROM all_users
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

All good, I have to startup the database, so I run `startup` but I receive:

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initorclcd.ora'
```

So let's go to check if the processes are working with `ps aux | grep pmon`:

```
oracle      22  0.0  0.2 2028516 66372 ?       Ss   21:52   0:00 ora_pmon_ORCLCDB
oracle    2421  0.0  0.0   9112   852 pts/1    S+   22:47   0:00 grep --color=auto pmon
```

It seems all good to me.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Check the database alert log. It should have more detailed information on what is wrong, though it looks like the database didn't start up correctly. Make sure the initorclcd.ora file is where it is supposed to be with the right permissions assigned, and that the oracle OS user can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Oracle database is called ORCLCDB (based on the PMON process).

But when you tried to start it, it referenced an init.ora file called: initorclcd.ora, which means it was looking for a database called "orclcd".

I think you've probably got a typo where you are setting the ORACLE_SID variable. Looks like you are missing a trailing "B"

1. Let's check what you have now: `echo $ORACLE_SID`
2. Setup the right ORACLE_SID: `export ORACLE_SID="ORCLCDB"`
3. Make this permanent by adding .bashrc of the user: `echo "export ORACLE_SID" >> ~/.bashrc`

Now run `sqlplus` and everything should be fine

Comment: typos are always the worst to track down :-)

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani  As for your last edit. I think you forgot to set the environment: `export ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB; . oraenv`.